# Powershell: moving items not working when filenames that have chars [ ]

Tags: powershell, filenames

Quick question about moving items with PowerShell: does anyone know why the following script does not work when the filename has the [ or ] chars on it? (ex.: **file1[VT].txt**)

```
ls j:\ | foreach { 
  $itemName = $_.Name.Replace('.', ' ') 
  $destination = ls | where { $itemName -match $_.Name } | select -First 1 
  if ($destination -ne $null) {       
    mi $_.PSPath $destination.PSPath -Verbose -WhatIf  
  } 
}
```

For instance, it will move the file if it's called **file1.txt** but it will simply ignore files named **file1[VT].txt**. I'm under the assumption that it's not finding the path to the file when it has chars [ or ] on its name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just using `-literalpath` parameter for `move-item`

```
ls j:\ | foreach { 
  $itemName = $_.Name.Replace('.', ' ') 
  $destination = ls | where { $itemName -match $_.Name } | select -First 1 
  if( $destination -ne $null){       
   mi -literalpath $_.PSPath $destination.PSPath -Verbose -WhatIf  
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that did it. Had completely forgotten about wildcard chars in powershell cmdlets (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa717088(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What if you change this line:

```
mi $_.PSPath $destination.PSPath -Verbose -WhatIf
```

to be this:

```
mi "$($_.PSPath)" "$($destination.PSPath)" -Verbose -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the -match operator, it treats pattern you are looking for (in your example $_.Name) as a regular expression. In .NET regex, the [ and ] characters are used to match a character against a group of tokens. For example, the regular expression

```
{"file1[vt]"}
```

will match the strings "file1v" and "file1t". In order to use the

Comment: add a solution for you suggestion. e.g. replace `where { $itemName -match $_.Name }` to `where { $itemName -match [regex]::escape($_.Name) }`

Comment: It's not really a regexp problem since it was getting the required files. However, when trying to move the files, they simply weren't being moved. I think it's because the  [] in the file name were being interpreted as wildcard chars instead of simple chars.