# PowerShell: batch copy files with % sign in name

Tags: powershell

I have a text file containing several thousand file names.  I am trying to copy these specific files to a subdirectory using this little script:

```
$names = "moves.txt"
$ext = ".zip"
$dest = "select"

foreach ($name in Get-Content $names)
  {
  echo "$name$ext"
  Move-Item -Path "$name$ext" -Destination "$dest"
  }
```

Unfortunately many of the filenames contain special characters, including a `%` sign.  This causes PS to barf.  Is there a way I can escape it, for any name in the list?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: moving items not working when filenames that have chars \[ \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842927/powershell-moving-items-not-working-when-filenames-that-have-chars) and [powershell move files with special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088017/powershell-move-files-with-special-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Powershell: moving items not working when filenames that have chars [ ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842927/powershell-moving-items-not-working-when-filenames-that-have-chars)

seems to indicate the -literalpath parameter for move-item might be what you seek.

if this is the answer credit is not mine, but CB's.

/edit So a simple change to the below should work:

```
$names = "moves.txt"
$ext = ".zip"
$dest = "select"

foreach ($name in Get-Content $names)
  {
  echo "$name$ext"
  Move-Item -LiteralPath "$name$ext" -Destination "$dest"
  }
```

For more info see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item

Comment: `LiteralPath` did the trick!  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want remove invalid char

```
 Function Clean-InvalidFileNameChars {
   param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
       Position=0,
       ValueFromPipeline=$true,
       ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
     [String]$Name
   )

   $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
   $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
   $res=($Name -replace $re)
   return $res.Substring(0, [math]::Min(260, $res.Length))
 }

 $names = "moves.txt"
 $ext = ".zip"
 $dest = "select"

 foreach ($name in Get-Content $names)
   {
   echo "$name$ext"
   $newname=Clean-InvalidFileNameChars $name
   echo "$name$ext"
   Move-Item -Path "$name$ext" -Destination "$dest"
   }
```